# How to compute the limit below by L'Hopital's rule?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity, taylor-expansion

> Let $\left(X_j\right)_{j\geq1}$ be i.i.d. with $E\{X_j\}=\mu$ and $\text{Var}\{X_j\}=\sigma^2$ (all $j$) with $0<\sigma^2<\infty$. Let $S_n=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}X_j$ and $Y_n=\dfrac{S_n-n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}$.
>  Let $\varphi_j$ be the characteristic function of $X_j-\mu$. Since the $\left(X_j\right)_{j\geq1}$ are i.i.d., $\varphi_j$ does not depend on $j$ and we write $\varphi$.
>   One can show that $\varphi_{Y_n}(u)=\left(\varphi\left(\dfrac{u}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)^n$. Then, one can expand $\varphi$ in a Taylor expansion about $u=0$ to get
>   $$\varphi(u)=1+0-\dfrac{\sigma^2u^2}{2}+u^2h(u)$$ with $h$ denoting the Peano remainder and $h(u)\rightarrow0$ as $u\rightarrow0$.
>   One can also show that
>   $$\varphi_{Y_n}(u)=e^{n\log\left(1-\frac{u^2}{2n}+\frac{u^2}{n\sigma^2}h\left(\frac{u}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)}$$
>   Taking limits as $n\rightarrow\infty$ and **using for example L'Hopital rule**, one gets $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\varphi_{Y_n}(u)=e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}$$

**MY QUESTION**: *how could the above limit be solved by using L'Hopital's rule?*

This is an indeterminate form $\infty\times0$. Thanks to the advice of user *Mark Viola* I get to the fact that limit can be rephrased as follows
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\varphi_{Y_n}(u)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}e^{\frac{\log\left(1-\frac{u^2}{2n}+\frac{u^2}{n\sigma^2}h\left(\frac{u}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}}$$
At this point, we get an indeterminate form $\left[\dfrac{0}{0}\right]$. By continuity of exponential function $e$, we have
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}e^{\frac{\log\left(1-\frac{u^2}{2n}+\frac{u^2}{n\sigma^2}h\left(\frac{u}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}}=e^{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(1-\frac{u^2}{2n}+\frac{u^2}{n\sigma^2}h\left(\frac{u}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}}$$
At this point, focusing on the limit 
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(1-\frac{u^2}{2n}+\frac{u^2}{n\sigma^2}h\left(\frac{u}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}$$
I have tried to solve it by means of L'Hopital rule.
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(1-\frac{u^2}{2n}+\frac{u^2}{n\sigma^2}h\left(\frac{u}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}\stackrel{H}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{d\log\left(1-\frac{u^2}{2n}+\frac{u^2}{n\sigma^2}h\left(\frac{u}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)}{dn}}{\frac{d\frac{1}{n}}{dn}}$$
I have some problem in computing $$\frac{d\log\left(1-\frac{u^2}{2n}+\frac{u^2}{n\sigma^2}h\left(\frac{u}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)}{dn}$$
Let $f(n)=\left(1-\frac{u^2}{2n}+\frac{u^2}{n\sigma^2}h\left(\frac{u}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)$. I know that $\dfrac{d\log\left(f(n)\right)}{dn}=\dfrac{f^{'}(n)}{f(n)}$ and my problems are related to the computation of $f^{'}(n)$ since I have no clue on how to compute the derivative of $\frac{u^2}{n\sigma^2}h\left(\frac{u}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\right)$ with respect to $n$, that is
$$\dfrac{d \frac{u^2}{n\sigma^2}h\left(\frac{u}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\right)}{dn} \tag{1}$$

*Could you please explain to me in detail how to solve derivative $(1)$ so as to get to the final result $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\varphi_{Y_n}(u)=e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}$?*

Comment: You can't use this rule on sequences, they are not differentiable

Comment: @Andronicus is right, but you can use [something very similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem).

Comment: Please don't use the title to try to communicate with individual users.

Comment: Ok, sorry @ArturoMagidin

Comment: Since you do a Taylor expansion on $\varphi$, why use L'Hospital? If you do a Taylor expansion on the $\log$ instead, you get the result in one line.

Comment: I simply followed the approach of my book, in which, after expanding $\varphi$ by means of Taylor expansion, one gets to the final result $e^{-u^2/2}$ for example by means of L'Hopital. So, I was curious about how it is possible to use L'Hopital after expanding so as to get to the desired result. Any suggestion about my specific doubt? @Raoul

Comment: I find it odd from the book to suggest using Taylor then L'Hospital. Here, as you saw, you get something quite ugly by using l'Hospital on the Taylor expansion. You also have to say something about $h'$, which is not obvious. Two things would feel more natural. 1) Use L'Hospital directly: $n \log \phi(u/\sigma \sqrt{n}) =  \log \phi(ux/\sigma)/x^2$ with $x = 1/\sqrt{n}$, and L'Hospital. 2) Use Taylor all the way: $\log \phi(u/\sigma \sqrt{n}) = \log(1 - u^2/(2\sigma^2n) + o(1/n)) = - u^2/(2\sigma^2n) + o(1/n)$, and multiply by $n$ to get the result.

Comment: Take for example your suggestion $1)$. When applying L'Hospital, I would get $\dfrac{\phi^{'}(ux/\sigma)}{\phi(ux/\sigma)2x}$. At this point, what should I do? To use L'Hospital once again? That is, what does $\dfrac{\phi^{'}(ux/\sigma)}{\phi(ux/\sigma)2x}$ correspond to? @Raoul

Comment: Yes, L'Hospital again works: you get $\frac{u^2}{\sigma^2} \frac{\phi''(ux/\sigma) \phi(ux/\sigma) - \phi'(ux/\sigma)^2}{2 \phi(ux/\sigma)^2}$, which tends to $-u^2/2$ indeed.

Comment: Why do you get that? When applying L'Hopital once again, I get $$\dfrac{\varphi^{''}(\frac{ux}{\sigma})}{2(x\cdot\varphi^{'}(\frac{ux}{\sigma})+\varphi(\frac{ux}{\sigma}))}$$ @Raoul

Comment: I see it as $[\phi'(ux/\sigma)/\phi(ux/\sigma)]/(2x)$, but your works just as fine. In both cases, you only need that $\phi(0) = 1$, $\phi'(0) = 0$, $\phi''(0) = - \sigma^2/2$.

Comment: It is $\varphi^{''}\left(0\right)=-\sigma^2$, but for the rest I get your reasoning except for the presence of $\frac{u^2}{\sigma^2}$ after the second application of L'Hopital. How does it show up? @Raoul

Comment: Yes, $\phi''(0) = -\sigma^2$ indeed, thanks. The $u^2/\sigma^2$ comes from the chain rule applied twice. The derivative of $\log \phi(ux/\sigma)$ is $\frac{u}{\sigma} \phi'(ux/\sigma) / \phi(ux/\sigma)$, and then you get another $u/\sigma$ when you differentiate again.

Comment: Thank you a lot, now it's all crystal-clear!!! Thanks for your time and patience. If you wish, you could summarize all your advice in an answer herebelow and I will be pleased to grant you the bounty which is open on this question, since you helped me significantly :) @Raoul

Comment: Thanks, but no worries, happy it makes sense now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**:

Let $x=1/n$.  Then examine the limit

$$\lim_{x\to0}\,\frac{\log\left(1-u^2x/2+(u^2/\sigma^2xh(u\sqrt{x}/\sigma))\right)}{x}$$

Can you proceed now?

Comment: Pardon, when applying L'Hopital, computing the derivative of the argument of $\log$, that is $\dfrac{d\left(1-u^2x/2+(u^2/\sigma^2xh(u\sqrt{x}/\sigma))\right)}{dx}$, what do you get as result of derivative wrt $x$ of $(u^2/\sigma^2xh(u\sqrt{x}/\sigma))$? I think you get $0$, but I cannot figure out why one gets $0$. Could you please explain this to me? @MarkViola

Comment: Take the derivative with respect to $x$.  For $\log(f(x))$, its derivative is $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$.  So you should end up with $\frac{-u^2/2+o(x^{1/2})}{1-u^2x/2+o(x^{3/2})}$

Comment: In your answer, shouldn'it be $$\lim_{x\to0}\,\frac{\log\left(1-u^2x/2+(u^2x/\sigma^2h(u\sqrt{x}/\sigma))\right)}{x}$$ instead of $$\lim_{x\to0}\,\frac{\log\left(1-u^2x/2+(u^2/\sigma^2xh(u\sqrt{x}/\sigma))\right)}{x}$$? Sorry, I have noticed this right now. Additionally, how do you treat the function $h$ when computing derivative with respect to $x$? @MarkViola

Comment: @Strictly_increasing Concerning your last comment, you both are right. Note that $a/bc = (a/b)c = (ac)/b$ by the usual bracketing convention. He did not write $a/(bc)$.

Comment: @Strictly_increasing As $\varepsilon-\delta$ stated, $u^2x/\sigma^2=u^2/\sigma^2 x$.  And $h(u\sqrt{x}/\sigma)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$. The notation implies that for any $\varepsilon>0$, $|h|\le \varepsilon \sqrt{x}$.

Comment: @Strictly_increasing Was there a reason for which you revoked your accepting the answer?  That is most curious.

Comment: Sorry, just a mistake I hadn't realized. I've re-accepted it :) @MarkViola