# Reference for "If $(a_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers with $\lim a_n^2=0$, then also $\lim a_n=0$"?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, reference-request

Could you please give me a good reference as to the below-quoted real analysis result?

> If $(a_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers with $\lim a_n^2=0$, then also $\lim a_n=0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition of a limit, for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $|a_n^2 - 0| < \varepsilon$ for all $n > N$.

Then we can see that the same holds for $a_n$: for any $\varepsilon > 0$, we know that for $\varepsilon_1 = \varepsilon^2$ there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $a_n^2 < \varepsilon_1\hspace{0.2cm}\forall n>N$, and this gives us $|a_n| < \varepsilon\hspace{0.2cm}\forall n>N$.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, use that $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is continuous:

If $a_n^2 \to 0$, then by continuity of $\sqrt{\cdot}$ we get $|a_n| \to 0 \iff a_n \to 0$.

Comment: As always, thank you a lot @ε-δ I know it's totally off-topic, but could you please give me some hint about how to solve the limit contained in the below link by L'Hopital ($h$ denotes the Peano remainder)?  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3507687/how-to-compute-this-limit-by-using-lhopitals-rule

Comment: I'll have a look!

Comment: Thank you again :) @ε-δ

Comment: Downvoter, kindly explain your downvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using definition of limit we know

$$
\forall \varepsilon > 0 \ \exists N \ge 0 : \forall n \ge N \  |a_n|^2 \le \varepsilon
$$

We want

$$
\forall \varepsilon > 0  \ \exists N \ge 0 : \forall n \ge N \  |a_n|\le \varepsilon
$$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: Not very helpful, I would say. But you should change those $M$'s to $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Also you need "$\forall\varepsilon>0$".

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure, but if $\lim a_n=a,$ then if you divide $\lim a_n^2$ by $a,$ you get$$\frac{\lim a_n^2}{\lim a_n}=\lim\frac{a_n^2}{a_n}=\lim a_n=\frac{0}{a}=a.$$If you multiply both sides by $a,$ you get $a=0,$ but if $a=0,$ you can't multiply both sides by $a$. Since$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\frac{\varepsilon}{a}=a\implies a^2=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\varepsilon,$$$a$ must converge to $0$.

Comment: You can only combine the quotient of the two limits into one limit if we know both limits exist (which is the question). Also, $\lim a_n$ is zero, so we cannot divide by it.